# Identifying custom models used in a Microsoft Form Recognizer composed model

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

We have a composed model containing 30 document models, all iterations of the same document.

We are looking to trace possible issues related to Azure FR performance with any specific custom model.

Is there a method for identifying the specific model is used within a composed model in MS Form Recognizer? Is this part of the JSON output?

Attempted to hard code a tag on each custom model through MS FR Studio, but that does not seem to be an option.

We are using the GA API released 8/31/2022 + ver 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I only use the Preview API, but in the JSON Result under "documents" is a Value "docType". The Value is "ComposedModel ID: ModelID"